# Android studio does not stay running

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, backend

So I created a backend for my app on Android Studio and the front end on react native. However, running the app on Android Studio doesn’t stay running. It terminates very quickly and I need it to stay running. Any ideas on how to fix this? I tried to add Android:persistent: true in the Android Manifest file but it didn’t work

This is what I see in my log cat

```
    "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar=51284:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @C:\Users\haroo\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_arg_file2069765526 com.example.prosubscriberapp.ApplicationKt
16:52:02.016 [main] INFO Application -- Autoreload is disabled because the development mode is off.
16:52:02.137 [main] INFO Application -- Application started in 0.88 seconds.
16:52:02.307 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory -- Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
16:52:02.693 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
16:52:02.695 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- Java version: 17
16:52:02.710 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
16:52:02.718 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
16:52:02.725 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- sun.misc.Unsafe.storeFence: available
16:52:02.732 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- java.nio.Buffer.address: available
16:52:02.740 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- direct buffer constructor: unavailable: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled
16:52:02.746 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
16:52:02.753 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable: class io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$7 cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @1e8f3784
16:52:02.761 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, {int,long}): unavailable
16:52:02.761 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- sun.misc.Unsafe: available
16:52:02.762 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- -Dio.netty.tmpdir: C:\Users\haroo\AppData\Local\Temp (java.io.tmpdir)
16:52:02.763 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
16:52:02.771 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- Platform: Windows
16:52:02.785 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: -1 bytes
16:52:02.786 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
16:52:02.797 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.CleanerJava9 -- java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
16:52:02.797 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
16:52:03.580 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup -- -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 24
16:52:03.720 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor -- -Dio.netty.globalEventExecutor.quietPeriodSeconds: 1
16:52:03.792 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap -- -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
16:52:03.792 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap -- -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096
16:52:03.949 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop -- -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
16:52:03.950 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop -- -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
16:52:04.073 [KtorShutdownHook] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is my MainActivity.kt file

```
package com.example.prosubscriberapp

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import io.ktor.server.engine.embeddedServer
import io.ktor.server.netty.Netty

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Start Ktor server
        val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
            proSubscriberApp()
        }
        server.start()
    }
}
```

and this is Application.kt

```
package com.example.prosubscriberapp


import com.example.prosubscriberapp.routes.planRoutes
import com.example.prosubscriberapp.routes.subscriptionRoutes
import com.example.prosubscriberapp.routes.transactionRoutes
import com.example.prosubscriberapp.routes.userRoutes
import com.example.prosubscriberapp.service.PlanService
import com.example.prosubscriberapp.service.RecommendationService
import com.example.prosubscriberapp.service.SubscriptionService
import com.example.prosubscriberapp.service.TransactionService
import com.example.prosubscriberapp.service.UserService
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.json
import io.ktor.server.application.Application
import io.ktor.server.application.install
import io.ktor.server.config.HoconApplicationConfig
import io.ktor.server.engine.applicationEngineEnvironment
import io.ktor.server.engine.embeddedServer
import io.ktor.server.netty.Netty
import io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation
import io.ktor.server.plugins.cors.routing.CORS
import io.ktor.server.routing.routing

fun Application.installCORS() {
    install(CORS) {
        anyHost() // Allow requests from any origin
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val environment = applicationEngineEnvironment {
        config = HoconApplicationConfig(ConfigFactory.load())
        // Other configuration settings
    }
    embeddedServer(Netty, environment).start()
}


fun Application.proSubscriberApp() {
    // Initialize services
    val userService = UserService()
    val planService = PlanService()
    val recommendationService = RecommendationService()
    val subscriptionService = SubscriptionService(recommendationService)
    val transactionService = TransactionService()

    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }

    installCORS()

    // Configure routes
    routing {
        userRoutes(userService)
        planRoutes(planService)
        subscriptionRoutes(subscriptionService)
        transactionRoutes(transactionService)
    }
}
```

Comment: did u check any crash in logcat or ANR if u did provide please

Comment: I have added what i see in my logcat

Comment: with exit code 0 its means appllication run sucessfully there is no error , can u debug your mainactivity

Comment: I have added them in

Answer (score 0):

apply layout and do like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Start Ktor server in a separate thread
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
                proSubscriberApp()
            }
            server.start()
        }
    }
}
```

The modification I provided will help ensure that the Ktor server continues running even if the Android activity is destroyed, which may help address the issue of the app terminating unexpectedly. By starting the server in a separate thread using Kotlin Coroutines, it will operate independently of the activity lifecycle.